# Does an Egyptian need a visa to transit in Istanbul?

Tags: transit-visas, turkey, egyptian-citizens

I am an Egyptian citizen going to Mozambique with a 2-hour connection in Istanbul. Do I need a visa for that?

Answer (score 1):

The official website states:

> If you will not leave the transit lounge at the airport you are not required to have transit visa. Otherwise, you have to make visa application to the nearest Turkish Representation.

So you do not need a transit visa if you have a 2-hour layover at Istanbul.